# How does the APDL code run and model the Heat flux being input to it?

Tags: ansys

'''

```
!   Commands inserted into this file will be executed just prior to the ANSYS SOLVE command.
!   These commands may supersede command settings set by Workbench.

!   Active UNIT system in Workbench when this object was created:  Metric (m, kg, N, s, V, A)
!   NOTE:  Any data that requires units (such as mass) is assumed to be in the consistent solver unit system.
!                See Solving Units in the help system for more information.
!
! /INPUT,HFLUX_func,,,1
*DIM,HEAT_FLX1,TABLE,6,22,1,,,,0 ! The last number corresponds to the ID number for the coordinate system
!
! Begin of equation: Q(x,y,t)=A*exp(B*(({X}-C)^2+({Y}-D*{TIME}-E)^2)/F^2)
!
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,0,1), 0.0, -999
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(2,0,1), 0.0
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(3,0,1), 0.0
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(4,0,1), 0.0
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(5,0,1), 0.0
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(6,0,1), 0.0
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,1,1), 1.0, -1, 0, 0.05, 0, 0, 2 ! "C" goes here 4te Zahl von Rechts
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,2,1), 0.0, -2, 0, 1, 2, 2, -1
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,3,1),   0, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0, -2
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,4,1), 0.0, -3, 0, 1, -2, 17, -1
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,5,1), 0.0, -1, 0, 0.01, 0, 0, 1  ! "D" goes here 4te Zahl von Rechts
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,6,1), 0.0, -2, 0, 1, -1, 3, 1
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,7,1), 0.0, -1, 0, 1, 3, 2, -2
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,8,1), 0.0, -2, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1   ! "E" goes here 4te Zahl von Rechts
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,9,1), 0.0, -4, 0, 1, -1, 2, -2
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,10,1), 0.0, -1, 0, 2, 0, 0, -4
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,11,1), 0.0, -2, 0, 1, -4, 17, -1
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,12,1), 0.0, -1, 0, 1, -3, 1, -2
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,13,1), 0.0, -2, 0, -3, 0, 0, -1 ! "B" goes here 4te Zahl von Rechts
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,14,1), 0.0, -3, 0, 1, -2, 3, -1
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,15,1), 0.0, -1, 0, 0.005, 0, 0, 0     ! "F" goes here 4te Zahl von Rechts
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,16,1), 0.0, -2, 0, 2, 0, 0, -1
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,17,1), 0.0, -4, 0, 1, -1, 17, -2
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,18,1), 0.0, -1, 0, 1, -3, 4, -4
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,19,1), 0.0, -1, 7, 1, -1, 0, 0
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,20,1), 0.0, -2, 0, 6e7, 0, 0, -1 ! "A" goes here 4te Zahl von Rechts
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,21,1), 0.0, -3, 0, 1, -2, 3, -1
*SET,HEAT_FLX1(0,22,1), 0.0, 99, 0, 1, -3, 0, 0
!
! End of equation: Q(x,y,t)=A*exp(B*(({X}-C)^2+({Y}-D*{TIME}-E)^2)/F^2)
!-->
sf,a1,hflux,%HEAT_FLX1%
```

FROM:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pYVqaXGLU9Y

Does it form a 3-dimensional matrix or is it a 4-dimensional matrix?
How is it that the APDL code is able to convert the same tabular data into a Heat flux distribution?
The values A, B, C, D can be changed by changing the 4th variable but what does this achieve accordingly?

Comment: Can you add some insights about what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: So i was trying to achieve a spot heat source which is transient in nature as it moves along one of the axises specified by the Co-Ordinate Id no 12. The spot heat source follows the Gaussian Distribution as shown in the equation above.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I came to this discussion so late; maybe someone else will benefit from this answer.  But that table is the coded representation of the equation; the table was written by Mechanical APDL's Function Tool.  That format is not really meant to be human usable.  There are numerical codes for all the operations (add, subtract etc) and variables (time, x position etc).  Anyway that format is really meant as storage so you can reuse the function in a different MAPDL model.  Search for 'function tool' in the MAPDL help for much more detail.  Mike